# How to remove blank spaces from data?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, web-scraping

I am a new python developer and I having a bit of an issue with dictionaries. When I attempt to scrape the data for the dictionary from a website there is blank spaces in the data, such as [this code snippet, showing the data with the space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMfSN.png), just to clarify I am trying to grab the number before 'ref'

So my question is how do i remove the blank spaces before and after the 'a' classes text

Comment: Have you tried `strip()` and then `split()` ?

Comment: @Shane useful but not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your PNG shows that the space is in a URL. I would use

urllib.unquote(string)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting